# Matlab: Generating an analog output signal (voltage) via NI DAQ during image acquisition

Tags: matlab, image-processing, nidaqmx

In Matlab, I am trying to provide an analog output signal (a voltage) at a certain point in time (or frame number) through a National Instruments DAQ while acquiring images with a USB3 camera.

If the image acquisition starts at t=0 (frame 0), the analog output signal should be provided at t=40s (or at frame 400 if we assume 10 fps) until t=42s (two seconds long). 
Image acquisition should continue during the generation of the output voltage (image acquisition should only stop at t=90s (or frame 900 if we count in frames)).

How can I incorporate my code for analog output signal (voltage) generation shown below into my Matlab script for image acquisition? Any help is very much appreciated!

```
s = daq.createSession('ni');

s.Rate = 8000

addAnalogOutputChannel(s,'Dev1',0,'Voltage');

outputData = [(linspace(0, 5, 16000)'); 0];
plot(outputData);
xlabel('Time');
ylabel('Voltage');

queueOutputData(s,outputData);

startBackground(s);
```

Comment: Can you start these two processes simultaneously? Does the time delay have to be _exactly_ 40s to 42s? Maybe you can add `0` voltages in 0s-40s and start the output immediately.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Yvon! I checked it out, and with some modifications of my image acquisition script, it works pretty well.